# Setup an integration test folder on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, junit

I would like to separate my integration tests from my unit tests on Android Studio using gradle.

Today, **androidTest** (expresso) and **test** (unit test) folders are created by default when you start an Android project.

Using gradle, I want to tell gradle build system and Android Studio that an onther folder (**integTest**) contains some tests (JUnit).

I've followed this article [here](https://selimober.com/gradle_unit_integration/), but I can't make it work. The first part - setting up the source test and the task - seems to be ok, but the second part isn't :

```
dependencies {  
    // ...
    integTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
    integTestCompile configurations.testCompile
    integTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
    integTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
    // ...
}
```

This is causing some errors :

```
Error:(139, 0) Could not get unknown property 'main' for SourceSet
container of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.
```

If I don't includes those lines, gradle is happy but the **integTest** folder is not recognize as a test folder (green color).

I also tried to manually set the **integTest** folder as a test resource (cmd + shift + a --> Mark Directory As.. Test Folder). With this manual step, I can run the tests but I keep getting the same error : empty test suite.

Is anyone manage to make that work ?

Thanks.

Comment: article is prolly about java plugin